# Determine prime number by user input using recursive method

Tags: java, math, methods

I need to create a program in Java that determines if a number is prime.

The user should enter any number, and the program will determine if it's prime or not, and display "not prime" or "prime." My code now compiles and runs but it always says a number isn't prime even if it is.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeNumber
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   int constant = 0;
   int variable = 0;
   System.out.println("Enter a Number to test if Prime or Not");
   constant = input.nextInt();
   variable = constant;
   double answer = 0.0;
   answer = testPrime(constant, variable);
   System.out.println(+answer);
   if (answer == 1)
    {
     System.out.println(+constant + " is a prime number.");
    }
   else
     {
     System.out.println(+constant + " is NOT a prime number.");
    }
   }

public static double testPrime(int number, int divide)
 {
  double prime = 0.0;
  prime = number%divide;
  if (prime > 0 && divide != number)
   {
    return testPrime(number, divide - 1);
   }
   else
   {
    return prime;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Why recursion? There is no reason to use recursion for this.

Comment: You should use integer/long for this. There are no floating point primes and it's much faster.

Comment: This is a brute force way to calculate a prime.  You should look at Fermat's Little Theorem [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Check-if-a-Number-Is-Prime) as well as some other algorithms if you want to do big prime numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (prime > 0 && divide != number)
```

This will never be true. Because your divide and number are always equal.

See that you have assigned `variable=constant` and that's what you pass to the method

```
constant = input.nextInt();
variable = constant;
answer = testPrime(constant, variable);
```

That said, you need go so complex to find out if a number is prime or not. Check the web for simple algorithms. See http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-determine-a-prime-number-in-java/ for example.

Comment: I'm supposed to use it, thats not what i'm having a problem with, its the why can't I display a prime number.

Comment: You are supposed to use what? Didn't you get if divide == number, then the if block I quoted will fail and it will always return "NOT PRIME". I think the answer is clear enough

Comment: I'm supposed to use the recursive method. so what should == be then?

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer as the OP wants recursion (homework I guess).

You need to only go till the square root of n to see if it has a divisor (divisor besides self will be < sqrt(n))

```
    boolean isPrime(int n) {
            if(n % 2 == 0)return false;
            int till  = (int)java.lang.Math.pow(n, 0.5); //(int)n / 2;
            for(int i= 3;i<till;i+=2) {
                if(n % i == 0) 
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Actually, they'll be less than SQRT(n), not n/2.

Comment: thanks, right how do you find n ^(1/2) in java, i will update the answer

Comment: `java.lang.Math.pow(n, 0.5)` or `java.lang.Math.sqrt()`

Comment: btw, the simplest way is to use condition `i * i <= n`

Comment: and I'm not using a boolean method

Comment: This can be optimized by first checking divisibility by 2, and then incrementing i by 2 in the for-loop over odd numbers (primes must be odd): `for(int i=3; i<till; i+=2;)`.  RiaD, that solution requires an extra multiplication every iteration, whereas calculating the square root is done before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I see you want recursion for this, so I converted tgkprog's answer to a recursive method (although his is definitely more efficient).  Additionally, I think you may want to return a prime factor if the input isn't prime?  I'm just speculating this judging from the OP's return value of a double instead of a boolean.  Mine will return an int though, because returning a double is silly.

```
int isPrime(int n){ //starter function
      if(n<=1) return n; //sanity check for weird inputs
      if(n % 2 == 0) return 2; //2 is a prime factor
      int start  = (int)java.lang.Math.pow(n, 0.5);
      return isPrime(n,start-(start%2)); //makes start odd if it wasn't already
}

int isPrime(int n, int testval){ //recursive function
       if(testval<=1) return 1; //n is prime, return n since it has no prime factors
       if(n % i == 0) 
           return i; //found a prime factor!
       return isPrime(n,i-2);
}
```

Comment: noticed your answer only after i posted below. +1 for getting the question right first time :) * not sure why you have 3 params in the 2nd fn. need only 2

Comment: @tgkprog ahh yes that's because I counted up.  Counting down removes the "till" parameter because I don't need to bounds check anymore (as long as it remains >1).  Although one could argue that prime factors are far more dense at smaller values, so starting from 3 should result in hitting prime factors quicker.

Comment: okay even though done some people's homework here, i think have given them some background too. if they are real developers they will find new problems to actually solve :-)

Answer (score 0):

with recursion

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeRecursion
{
    static int dbg;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter non 0 if you want debug :");
        dbg = input.nextInt();
        long constant = 3;
        long variable = 0;
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Enter a Number to test if Prime or Not (1 to exit)");
            constant = input.nextLong();
            if(constant < 3){
                if(constant == 2){
                    System.out.println("2 is a special prime");
                }
                return;
            }
            if(constant % 2 == 0){
                System.out.println(constant + " is NOT a prime number, even number.");
            }else{
                variable = (long)Math.pow(constant, 0.5);
                variable = (variable % 2 == 1) ? variable : variable + 1;//odd number
                double answer = 0.0;
                answer = testPrime(constant, variable);
                System.out.println("End answer : " + answer);
                if (answer == 1){
                    System.out.println(+constant + " is a prime number. answer : "  + answer);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println(constant + " is NOT a prime number.answer : "  + answer);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    static double testPrime(long number, long divide)
    {
        double prime = 0.0;
        prime = (double)number / divide;
        if(dbg > 0){
            System.out.println("Debug number " + number + " | divide " + divide + " |prime : "  + prime + " | Math.abs(prime) " + Math.abs(prime));
        }
        if (prime == ((long)prime))//whats the best way to do this?
        {
            //divided evenly
            return divide;
        }
        else{
            return testPrime(number, divide - 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> the recursive function for me goes like-Correct me if i am wrong.Thank you.calling statement >Boolean b=isPrime(number,number-1);
>   recursive function-

```
void isPrime(int p,int d);
{
int prime=p%d;
if((p==0&&d>1)||p%2==0)
return true;//that the number is not prime
if(d==1)
return false;
else
return isPrime(p,d-2);//calls the function again
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well I am directly giving you all the code instead of writing snippet. Hope you all may like this one as I have tried my best to make it as simple as possible.
The code is :>

```
import java.util.*;
class Prime_Number
{
    static int c=0;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int n,i,sq=0;
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        Prime_Number ob=new Prime_Number();
        System.out.print("Enter a no.:>");
        n=in.nextInt();
        i=n;
        sq=(int)(Math.sqrt(n));//square root is been taken since a no. cannot have factors greater than its square root
        int k=ob.prime_Chk(n,i,sq);
           if(k==1)
              {
                 System.out.println("Prime");
              }
                 else
                     {
                       System.out.println("Non-Prime");
                      }
      }
public int prime_Chk(int g,int i,int sq)
    {
        if(i==sq)
        {
            return c;
        }
        else
        {
            if(g%i==0)
            {
                c++;
            }
            i--;
            return(prime_Chk(g,i,sq));
        }
    }
}
```

Well in the prime() I have taken int i , int sq and int g as arguments.Instead of those if you wish then you can take other variables also.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW8R_T03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int simple = prime(n,n-1);
        System.out.println(simple==1 ? "prime" : "not prime");

    }

    static int prime(int x, int y){
        int div = 1;
        if (y==0 || y==1){
             return div;
        }
        if (x%y==0){
            div = y;
        } else {
            div = prime (x, --y);
        }
        return div;
    }


}
```

Comment: Please explain all answers you post. This is just a code dump!